# Storing and retrieving secrets in Azure keyvault with variable Groups in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure, azure-pipelines-yaml

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Using Azure devops pipelines and want to store my secr[![enter image description here][2]][2]ets in Azure KeyVault? How to use a variable group with keyvault integration to retrieve my secrets values and use within my DevOps pipeline.
Below is Yaml script which has hardcoded values of service connection and storage account name,key for to store the terraform tfstate files, my question is how we can pass it as secure type so that no one can see my data. I have created AzureKeyVault and it is linked to provided service connection.

````
trigger: none
#########################
# Declare Build Agents:-
#########################
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

######################
#DECLARE PARAMETERS:-
######################
parameters:
- name: ResourceGroup
  displayName: Please Provide the Resource Group Name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: Region
  displayName: Please Provide the Region Name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>

- name: sqlserver
  displayName: Please Provide the sqlserver Name:-
  type: object
  default: <Please provide the required Name>
######################
#DECLARE VARIABLES:-
######################
variables:
  TF_VAR_ResourceGroup: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroup }}
  TF_VAR_REGION: ${{ parameters.Region }}
  TF_VAR_SQLSERVER_NAME: ${{ parameters.sqlserver }}
  ###################
# Declare Stages:-
###################
stages:
  - stage: tfvalidate
    jobs:
      - job: validate
        continueOnError: false
        steps:
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              backendServiceArm: $(serviceconnection) # it should pick from my azureKeyvault
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'AzureDevops' # it should pick from my azureKeyvault
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'azuredevopsdev' # it should pick from my azureKeyvault
              backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstatedev' # it should pick from my azureKeyvault
              backendAzureRmKey: 'terrafrom.tfstate' # it should pick from my azureKeyvault
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'
  - stage: tfdeploy
    condition: succeeded('tfvalidate')
    dependsOn: tfvalidate
    jobs:
      - job: apply
        steps: 
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              backendServiceArm: 'dev-Automationaccount_OIDC'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'AzureDevops'
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'azuredevopsdev'
              backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstatedev'
              backendAzureRmKey: 'terrafrom.tfstate'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: plan
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'plan'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'dev-Automationaccount_OIDC'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: apply
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'apply'
              commandOptions: '-auto-approve'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'dev-Automationaccount_OIDC'
              backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstatedev'
              backendAzureRmKey: 'terrafrom.tfstate'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'
  - stage: tfdeploy
    condition: succeeded('tfvalidate')
    dependsOn: tfvalidate
    jobs:
      - job: apply
        steps: 
          - task: TerraformInstaller@0
            inputs:
              terraformVersion: 'latest'

          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: init
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'init'
              backendServiceArm: 'dev-Automationaccount_OIDC'
              backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'AzureDevops'
              backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'azuredevopsdev'
              backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstatedev'
              backendAzureRmKey: 'terrafrom.tfstate'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: validate
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'validate'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: plan
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'plan'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'dev-Automationaccount_OIDC'
          - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
            displayName: apply
            inputs:
              provider: 'azurerm'
              command: 'apply'
              commandOptions: '-auto-approve'
              environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'dev-Automationaccount_OIDC'
```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0lU5.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEm6h.png
````

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the correct role to the service principal on the KV:

1. find the linked service connection

- project settings > service connections > manage service principal (opens azure portal) > copy the title of the SP

2. go to your KV and assign permission to this SP

- Access Control (IAM) > +Add > Add role assignment > **contributor** > User, group or SP > select members: paste the copied title of your SP >> select+review&assign

3. go to Azure Dev/Ops and connect your KV + add secrets you want to use
4. Test inside YAML:

- YAML config:
  [image]
- And inside the logs of the pipeline:
  [image: [img1]]

--> The secret is not exposed in the pipeline

note: make sure that access policies for the SP and the specific KV are set correctly, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal

note: when you run the pipeline you might have to give explicit permissions for the pipeline to access the library group, this only needs to be done once.

## Alternative method:

Since you have already set up a connection you can also use an AzureCLI task to get credentials and persistent them through your pipeline,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines

Set `addSpnToEnvironment` to true, and use something like this to set the value(s): `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SECRET;issecret=true;isoutput=true]$Key"`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response @Roelof, How my service connection works when i updated in my script? could please assist me with the same which iam expecting to my above provided yaml script, as you said ``- script: | echo $(test)``  how it works my script **backendServiceArm: **

Comment: Once you have set up the Key Vault connection, and reference the correct library group in variables, you can simply set it in you yaml like so; backendServiceArm: $(serviceconnectionname)

Comment: I have setup the key vault connection and added serviceconnection name i want to use but getting this ##[error]Error: Input required: backendServiceArm, attached the screenshots of keyvault for ref,modified the above yaml script as backendServiceArm: $(serviceconnection) on tfvalidate on first stage itself my getting mentioned error.

Comment: This error probably means that the 'serviceconnection' variable is empty. I would recommend trying with a simple bash task and doing an echo so that you are sure the pipeline is reading the variable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another approach I have tried to reproduce in my environment as below and got positive results.**

Step 1: Create an Azure key vault and add secrets.

[image]

Step 2: Create a service principal and note down the app Id, tenant id and password for later use.
[image]

Step 3: Add service principle to key vault access policies as shown below.

•   Navigate to the Access policies in the key vault and click on create.
[image]

[image]

•   Select the required permissions and click on next.

[image]

Enter the object id which we created in step 2 and click Review+create.

Step 4: Create a service connection in the azure devops with the details created in step 2.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Fill these details and click create.

Step 5: Navigate to Pipelines > Library and click on Variable group

[image]

[image]

Add the required keys, secretes and certificates under variables.

[image]

Step 6: Refer the variable group in the Azure pipelines as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sourav - this steps i have already done now my yaml script as mentioned above **backendServiceArm: ** should take my service connection name as i have stored in variable group. Please assist me to solve this